# SQL Query in Oracle showing less records than those satisfying criterion

Tags: oracle, datetime

I need to check whether a user inputted Month-Year combination falls in between from_dt and to_dt column of the table.My Query is As follows:

```
SELECT emp_code,
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(from_dt),'MM') = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((1||'/'||:for_mon||'/'|| :for_year),'DD/MM/YYYY'),'MM') 
       THEN LAST_DAY(TO_DATE((1||'/'||:for_mon||'/'|| :for_year),'DD/MM/YYYY')) -  TO_DATE(FROM_DT) +1


  WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(from_dt),'DD/MM/YYYY')<=
 to_char(TO_DATE((1||'/'||:for_mon||'/'||
 :for_year),'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
        AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(to_dt),'DD/MM/YYYY')>=to_char(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE((1||'/'||:for_mon||'/'||
 :for_year),'DD/MM/YYYY')),'DD/MM/YYYY') 
       Then LAST_DAY(TO_DATE((1||'/'||:for_mon||'/'|| :for_year),'DD/MM/YYYY'))
            -TO_DATE((1||'/'||:for_mon||'/'|| :for_year),'DD/MM/YYYY')+1

ELSE 0
END AS Leave
FROM TestTable
```

But this query shows only one employee's leave count for the given month-year combo while other employees' leave count also should be shown as their from_dt and to_dt also falls in the same month-year.
Moreover its is showing no exceptions.

I've tried setting values of NLS_COMP and NLS _SORT too, but with no gain.

Comment: When comparing date you should use date arithmetics, *not* string comparison. At the very least, the later is error prone ... and in many case leads to almost unreadable code.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings, you use [lexicographically comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). That is, you are using the *dictionary* order. Depending your date string format, the lexicography order might or might not be the same as the "natural" date order:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(from_dt),'DD/MM/YYYY')
         <=to_char(TO_DATE((1||'/'||:for_mon||'/'||:for_year),'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

For example, the following table is lexicographically ordered using the `DD/MM/YYYY` format:

```
TO_CHAR(DATA,'DD/MM/YYYY')
01/12/2014
14/10/2013
24/11/2014
```

As you can see, such format does not preserve "natural" date order, and so is *not* suitable for date comparison. On  the other hand, the `YYYY/MM/DD` is:

```
TO_CHAR(DATA,'YYYY/MM/DD')
2013/10/14
2014/11/24
2014/12/01
```

Either switch to that date format, or *better*, get rid of those *date to string* comparison and use plain *date arithmetics* (take a look at [`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) for example)